# Guava's Ranges.asSet outputting infinite list

Tags: java, guava, date-range

I am trying to get a date range using Guava's new [Range](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) functionality, via

```
Range<Date> dateRange = Ranges.range(start, BoundType.CLOSED, end, BoundType.CLOSED);
```

My goal is to get the hours in this date range. So I have created a DiscreteDomain like such:

```
private static final DiscreteDomain<Date> HOURS = new DiscreteDomain<Date>() {

    public Date next(Date value) {
        return addHours(value, 1);
    }

    private Date addHours(Date value, int i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(value);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    public Date previous(Date value) {
        return addHours(value, -1);
    }

    public long distance(Date start, Date end) {
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(start);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(end);

        return cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    public Date minValue() {
        return new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    public Date maxValue() {
        return new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
};
```

If I merely sysout the output, I get the closed set

```
[Thu Feb 24 00:00:00 EST 2011..Thu Feb 24 00:02:00 EST 2011]
```

I really want to see each hour in the range, however, so I try a for loop:

```
for (Date hour : hours) {
    System.out.println(hour);
}
```

When running this block, I seem to get an infinite set, beginning at the left side of the range, but not stopping at the right side, making me kill the IDE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be due to the behavior of the `Iterator` returned by the `ContiguousSet` (returned by `Range.asSet()`):

```
  @Override public UnmodifiableIterator<C> iterator() {
    return new AbstractLinkedIterator<C>(first()) {
      final C last = last();

      @Override
      protected C computeNext(C previous) {
        return equalsOrThrow(previous, last) ? null : domain.next(previous);
      }
    };
  }

  private static boolean equalsOrThrow(Comparable<?> left,
      @Nullable Comparable<?> right) {
    return right != null && compareOrThrow(left, right) == 0;
  }

  private static int compareOrThrow(Comparable left, Comparable right) {
    return left.compareTo(right);
  }
```

It only stops when the next computed value is **equal** to the right bound of the range.

In your case, have you tried calling it using `Thu Feb 24 02:00:00` instead of `Thu Feb 24 00:02:00` for the right bound of your range?

I think this behavior is problematic, and it might be worth asking if `equalsOrThrow()` could be changed to check for `left <= right` instead of `left == right`

---

Also, your `distance()` method is incorrect. It should return the distance in hours, not in milliseconds, according to the method contract.

---

### EDIT

All this being said, I believe the real problem is that, according to the [DiscreteDomain's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html) javadoc:

> A discrete domain always represents
>   the entire set of values of its type;
>   it cannot represent partial domains
>   such as "prime integers" or "strings
>   of length 5."

In your case, you are attempting to create a discrete domain over *hourly dates*, which is a partial domain of all dates. This is, I think, the root cause of the problem. When you have a partial domain, the `equalsOrThrow` method becomes unreliable, and it can "miss" the right bound of your range.

Comment: Spent too much time editing my answer and I see you had already edited yours to mention the partial domain problem!

Comment: Ahah, yeah, I thought about this just after posting, and re-checked the DiscreteDomain's javadoc... I'm a little trigger happy on the edit button. Sorry about this. Though I guess our answers complement each other, covering the whole domain ;)
I'm wondering if it would be worth it for Guava to throw an `IllegalStateException` when it sees that the iterator's next element is strictly greater than the upper bound (which would indicate a problem with the discrete domain).

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it worked fine for me. @eneveu already pointed out the issue with your `distance` method as well. I'm also guessing that there's some minor difference at the millisecond level between `start` and `end` which means that you'll never actually get a `Date` equal to `end` by adding hours to `start`.

However, that's all just symptoms of using the classes in a way they aren't designed to work. The Javadoc for `DiscreteDomain` states:

> A discrete domain always represents the *entire* set of values of its type; it cannot represent partial domains such as "prime integers" or "strings of length 5."

A `DiscreteDomain` of "hours" does not represent the domain of all possible `Date` objects and as such breaks its contract.